# Configure Gradle to publish sources and javadoc

Tags: java, gradle

How do I configure Gradle to publish sources and javadoc jars to a repository?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add the following code to the build script:

```
task packageJavadoc(type: Jar, dependsOn: 'javadoc') {
    from javadoc.destinationDir
    classifier = 'javadoc'
}
task packageSources(type: Jar, dependsOn: 'classes') {
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
    classifier = 'sources'
}
artifacts {
    archives packageJavadoc
    archives packageSources
}
```

Tested with Gradle 1.10

Comment: Beaten to it :p I also make `sourcesJar` (which you call `packageSources` depend on `classes`; it avoids generating a source jar if the source fails to compile :p

Comment: Thanks @fge, I tested what you suggested and updated the answer

Answer (score 55):

### Solution as of Gradle 6.0

Here’s the somewhat minimal configuration you can use if you’re on Gradle 6.0 or later; note the **newly introduced `withSourcesJar()` and `withJavadocJar()`** methods:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group = 'com.example'

java {
    withSourcesJar()
    withJavadocJar()
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = 'file:///tmp/my-repo'
        }
    }
    publications {
        myJava(MavenPublication) {
           from components.java
       }
    }
}
```

Of course, you can also use the `ivy-publish` plugin instead of `maven-publish`.

See also the Gradle docs:

- on [the two new methods](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java-extension)
- on [the `maven-publish` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0/userguide/publishing_maven.html)
- on [the `ivy-publish` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0/userguide/publishing_ivy.html)

Comment: It should be the accepted answer as it's the most reliable and most straightforward solution. I confirm that it works with Gradle 8.1.

Answer (score 26):

2017, Gradle 4.0 Edition:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

            artifact sourceJar
            artifact packageJavadoc
        }
    }
}

javadoc {
  source = sourceSets.main.allJava
  classpath = configurations.compileClasspath

  options
  {
    setMemberLevel JavadocMemberLevel.PUBLIC
    setAuthor true

    links "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/"
  }
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
  classifier = 'sources'
  from sourceSets.main.allJava
}

task packageJavadoc(type: Jar) {
    from javadoc
    classifier = 'javadoc'
}
```

Works with `gradle publish` and `gradle publishToMavenLocal`

Comment: Anybody have an update to this for 2019 Gradle 5.4.1?

Comment: @dammason: no but maybe my [2019 update for Gradle 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58845587/1797912) will help you ;-)

Comment: BTW, @sobutterysosmooth: +1 but is applying the `maven` plugin really required?

Answer (score 3):

Paolo Fulgoni's answer used to work for until I bumped up my Gradle version to 3.1. To get the `packageJavadoc` Task to work with Gradle 3.1 I found I had to make a slight tweak to it as follows:

```
task packageJavadoc(type: Jar) {
    from javadoc
    classifier = 'javadoc'
}
```