# Publishing artifacts(with sources and javadoc) with gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to create a gradle file in order to publish my artifacts (`.jar`, `sources.jar` and `javadoc.jar`).

Up to now, I've been able to write this gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'net.nemerosa.versioning' version '2.5.1'
}

targetCompatibility = 1.8

eclipse {
    project {
        name = 'OAuthz Library'
        natures 'org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleprojectnature'
    }
    classpath {
        downloadSources = true
        downloadJavadoc = true

        defaultOutputDir = file('build-eclipse')
    }
    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:1.3.7'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.api:api-all:1.0.0-M30'
    compile 'com.whalin:Memcached-Java-Client:3.0.2'
    compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '2.14.3'
    compile 'commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.10'
}

group = 'com.living'
version = versioning.info.display

manifest {
    attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'OAuthz Library'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {

        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username 'user'
                password 'passwd'
            }
            url "$url"
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.1'
}
```

I've been able to publish my package on repository, nevertheless:

1. The published package is telling me that it has no dependencies.
2. I'd like to publish sources and java docs artifacts.

Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904269/configure-gradle-to-publish-sources-and-javadoc for the source and javadoc publishing

Comment: This post is only related with how to *generate* the artifacts. I've already seen that, nevertheless, I don't quite to figure out how to publish them on my maven repository. And what about the "normal" jar artifact?

Comment: Comparing to the [manual](https://docs.gradle.org/3.1/userguide/publishing_maven.html#sec:publishing_component_to_maven), I think there are a few things you still have to set

Comment: I've already seen this manual. Nevertheless, I don't quite to figure out what's remaining yet.

Answer (score 6):

1) You include a publishing block, but include no artifacts. That way only a pom is created. You need to include a `from components.java` in your publishing definition:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java 
        }
    }
...
```

2) You need to first create the artifacts:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
```

Then include the artifacts into your publication:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact sourcesJar
            artifact javadocJar
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: Thanks @blackbuild. I don't quite figure out what's `components.java` is refereing to... As you can see I've left it empty on script.

Comment: @Jordi Its says to take the component name java. This one is automatically defined by the java plugin and includes all classed from main/java /by default). For War projects, this would be `components.web`.

Comment: Now it's getting me this message: `Exception thrown while executing model rule: PublishingPlugin.Rules#publishing(ExtensionContainer)
> Could not find method artifact() for arguments [task ':sourcesJar'] on Publication container.`

Answer (score 1):

I use the [nebula-publishing-plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-publishing-plugin)

```
plugins {
    id 'nebula.javadoc-jar' version '4.4.4'
    id 'nebula.source-jar' version '4.4.4'
}
```

If you don't want to use these plugins, you could use the code from [the docs](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-publishing-plugin#nebulasource-jar)

```
tasks.create('sourceJar', Jar) {
    dependsOn tasks.classes
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
    classifier 'sources'
    extension 'jar'
    group 'build'
}
publishing {
    publications {
        nebula(MavenPublication) { // if maven-publish is applied
            artifact tasks.sourceJar
        }
        nebulaIvy(IvyPublication) { // if ivy-publish is applied
            artifact tasks.sourceJar
        }
   }
}
```